# Padding zeros in C

Tags: c

I have to add zero to the shorter bit string, but if this doesn't work for

```
str1  = 0011
str2  = 0101111100011
```

but it works if

```
str1  = 0101111100011
str2  = 0011
```

```
void addLeadingZero(char* str1 , char* str2) {
    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(str2);
    int diff = (len1 > len2) ? len1 : len2; 

    while (len1 < diff) {
        for (int i = len1; i >= 0; i--) {
            str1[i + 1] = str1[i]; // expend the shorter array length.
            //until there is no difference in lengths.
        }

        str1[0] = '0'; //add zeros to it.
        len1++;
    }// loop stops when max diff is reached.

    while (len2 < diff) { //same concept as above.
        for (int i = len2; i >= 0; i--) {
            str2[i + 1] = str2[i];
        }

        str2[0] = '0';
        len2++;
    }
}
```

output :

```
0000000000011
011
```

expected output

```
0000000000011
0101111100011
```

Comment: Do the arrays have enough space for you to insert additional characters?  That seems a pretty shaky assumption.

Comment: Do you really need to update or create an array to contain the extra zero-padding, or would it be sufficient to simply print the padded result?

Comment: I tested here and it worked both cases. The strings are created/initialized like this: `char str1[100] = {0,}; strcpy(str1, "0011");`

Comment: Are the arrays in fact modifiable? (Note: string literals are not.)

Comment: Side note: if you really do want to modify the shorter array in place, then a single `memmove()` would be a much simpler and cleaner way to make space for the padding, and a single `memset()` would be a simpler and cleaner way of writing the padding.

Comment: To do do this safely the prototype should be changed to ensure 1) it is not using string literals, which are created in read only memory, 2) each string argument should come with length information.

Comment: Question: Why are the longest examples 13 chars long?

Comment: Edwin Zheng, Please post a [mcve].

Comment: A better name for the `diff` variable would be `max`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pad a string, the containing buffer must have enough space for the padding and the original string, and it must be modifiable. Otherwise, [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) will be the result.

String literals are not modifiable, and should not be passed to such a function.

Arrays which have their size determined by the initialization (e.g., `char foo[] = "bar";`) will not contain any additional room for padding.

Dynamically allocated buffers could be resized with [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) to create space, or a new buffer could be allocated for the result.

---

For a different method, using standard library functions:

Use [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) to move the existing string towards the end of the buffer.

Use [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) to fill the gap.

A simple example where the buffers are explicitly sized to have enough room:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void pad(char *string, size_t length, size_t new_length)
{
    size_t diff = new_length - length;
    memmove(string + diff, string, length + 1);
    memset(string, '0', diff);
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[64] = "123";
    char b[64] = "456789";

    size_t a_len = strlen(a);
    size_t b_len = strlen(b);

    if (a_len > b_len)
        pad(b, b_len, a_len);
    else if (b_len > a_len)
        pad(a, a_len, b_len);

    puts(a);
    puts(b);
}
```

Output:

```
000123
456789
```

Comment: `memmove()` and `memset()` is what I would do, too, but in cases where the OP's approach does not work, I would not expect that combination to work either.

Comment: Ooops,   Open mouth, insert foot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `diff` does not show the difference.

You can use memmove and memset for this task:

```
void addLeadingZero(char* str1 , char* str2) 
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(str1);    
    size_t len2 = strlen(str2);
    char *wrk = len1 > len2 ? str2 : str1; 
    size_t diff = len1 > len2 ? (len1 - len2) : (len2 - len1);

    if(diff)
    {
        memmove(wrk + diff, wrk, len1 > len2 ? len2 + 1 : len1 + 1);
        memset(wrk, '0', diff);
    }
}
```

Remember that `str1` & `str2` have to be modifiable and large enough to accommodate the padded string.

Comment: Sure, but is there some reason to think that this will work in any case where the OP's version does not?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, because he is not calculating the diff properly

Comment: The OP's `diff` variable is just misleadingly named.  It is not the length difference, but rather the longer length, and *it is used appropriately for that*.